# Choregraphe doesn't store the movements of NAO in keyframes

Tags: timeline, keyframe, nao-robot, choregraphe

When I use the timeline box in Choregraphe I set the movements in the keyframes via the inspector widget. I saw people using a motion widget but in my version it doesn't appear, instead there is the inspector widget which is similar but it doesn't have the drawing of the art that you selected. Now the problem is that if I set a position (for ex right arm elbow 30 degrees) and then switch arm to set other parameters the previus position (the right elbow) doesn't get saved. Also when I set a new position nao does it quickly and then returns in the standing position (this problem is both in the virtual and real robot) (also it's not a problem related to the frames that are too high or the position of the keyframe in the timeline). Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In choregraphe, you need to click to the bullet next to the joint slider, if the bullet is red then it's recorded, else it's not.

Comment: Ok that solved my record problem thank you. In the last part of the question I also asked why Nao, when I use the sliders, moves the part quickly and then return in the standing position. I am trying to record a position which requires multiple values to be changed so I need nao to stay still (at the value that I gave him) to figure out where to put the sliders.

Comment: By chance is it because the autonomous life or your behavior is already running ?

Comment: The behavior isn't running when I store the movements in keyframes, autonomous life could be but the thing is that it does this even with the virtual robot. I tried switching choregraphe version (it was like 2.0.something, the one that I usualy use is the latest) but it didn't change anything. When I try to store a movement nao (simulated and real) doesn't remain still and moves in different positions. The arrows under the sliders in the inspector widget are always blue and never green. Do you know what may cause this?

Comment: I've retried it and don't see the problem. here's a quick record in simulated mode: https://youtu.be/bnQpoKbz03M. Btw: if it occurs when you change your time, then beware where you're clicking: clicking in the number doesn't positionnate NAO to the recorded key, while clicking in the keyline set the interpolated position between two keys, as seen in the end of the video (even if the clicks are not perceptible)

Comment: Little update: today I tried on the real nao and the problem was that autonomous life was running while I was trying to register the keyframes. I still do not get why you have a motion widget and I have the inspector but tbh I don't care too much. Tysm for the help!